# What is the status of Koheles and Shir HaShirim in the bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, kohelet, shir-hashirim

Depending on the Tanna, Koheles and Shir HaShirim might not be considered a part of Tanach, but merely written from Shlomo HaMelech's wisdom. Therefore, unlike books of Tanach, one who touches these scrolls does not become tamei (see Eduyos 5:3, Yadayim 3:5, with Peirush HaMishnayos to Eduyos ibid.).

Does this mean that, according to those opinions, one may even carry those scrolls into a bathroom, or speak verses of them, unlike books of Tanach? Or are they still considered Torah and still cannot be brought into a bathroom, but because they were not composed with Ruach HaKodesh, they weren't able to be canonized into Tanach?

(Just to clarify, we pasken like Beis Hillel, and therefore these books are a part of Tanach halacha l'ma'aseh. Therefore, I have not tagged this question [halacha](/questions/tagged/halacha).)

Comment: Kohelet has God's name in it (eg. 1:13)

Comment: @DoubleAA Okay, then the Pesukim that don't have It.

Comment: What about Esther?

Comment: @ezra What about it? L'maskana it was written with ruach hakodesh and is therefore a part of kesuvim.

Comment: @DonielF - From where do you learn out that Shir HaShirim and Koheles do not have the same kedusha as other books within the Tanach?

Comment: @ezra According to certain opinions, I said. Notably Beis Shammai according to both R' Yishmael and R' Shimon. Again, Halacha l'ma'aseh, this question doesn't apply.

Comment: Why would these be different from the Apocrypha?